# Как авторезайзить колонки по высоте относительно друг друга

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, height

Первое правильное состояние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второе состояние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, чтобы при втором состоянии текст в колонке посередине показывался полностью и чтобы высота колонок подстраивалась под высоту наибольшего столбца.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 300px;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.cropline {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="item">column1column1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item cropline">longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="item">column2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Что бы текст в центральной коленке показывался полностью".
Вы вешаете `-webkit-line-clamp: 3;` разумеется текст будет обрезаться до 3х строк.

Comment: @MaxWatson нужно, чтобы если колонка посередине имеет самую большую высоту, то она обрезалась до трёх строк, а если другая колонка становится самой большой, то обрезалась пропорционально, то есть если текст в соседних колонках совсем большой, то в колонке посередине текст показывался полностью

Comment: @MaxWatson если можно использовать что-то другое, чтобы обрезалось после 3х строк и при этом, чтобы показывался текст относительно других высот, то я отказаться от -webkit-line-clamp: 3; только за

Comment: Без js не обойтись, посчитать количество символов в каждой колонке и кропать или отображать полностью